# Suggestions on plotting 3 1-Dimensional variables

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I have taken readings on my software defined radio. I have three quantities, frequency, power and error rate. I would like to keep frequency on my x-axis as the latter quantities are measured with respect to frequency. Now I need to plot them on a single curve so that i can see frequency vs power and frequency vs error rate in one shot. I have been looking at matplotlib for quite some time but I see the 3d scatter plots and they seem to not convey the picture i want. So my question is

1. Is 3d plot useless in my case and I better plot 2 graphs and join the y axes of both graphs together so that I could see both the graphs on top of each other.
2. Is there a way in python or matlab such that  you plot a 3d curve and then if you move the cursor you can see frequency vs power and if you move the cursor the other way you can see frequency vs error rate.

Any other ideas on how i can represent my readings better will be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered using `surf` or `mesh`?

Comment: I have seen both. But they seem to be not so clear that if i see graph i am not instantly and accurately recognising my  y parameters. I might be wrong as i am seeing surf and mesh for the first time today. If you can show me an example that would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have 3D data? So for each frequency-power-pair there are multiple error rates? Or do you just have 3 variables? The reason I'm asking is to be clear on your (1.) question.

Comment: Re-reading, it looks like you have one independent variable (frequency) and two dependent (power and error rate). For that case, 2D plots would be better. Sorry for the confusion. Is there a reason you need them on top of each other and can't plot them next to each other? `subplot` could be useful

Comment: @Schorsch I have one frequency and based on that i have a power reading and error rate, again power and error are independent w.r.t to each other.

Comment: I agree with David K, `subplot` should convey the information you want. Alternatively, `plotyy` is also a possibility.

Comment: @DavidK plotting two graphs separately is just normal. So I was thinking if i could do some 3d plot where at one view i could check both instead of seeing two graphs for one particular independent variable.

Comment: Sometimes "normal" is the best way to present the information...

Comment: @DavidK Ya you are right. That's what i think is better for my problem now. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two sets of data share the same dependant variable (x-axis), it is common in scientific literature at least to plot them both in the following manner to save space:

[image: Example]

This is preferred to twining the xaxis which can cause confusion for some people. It works especially well if features are to be compared.

This plot was generated using:

```
import pylab as py

x = py.linspace(0,10,1000)
y = py.sin(x) 
z = py.sinc(x)

ax1 = py.subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_xticklabels([])  # Remove the xticks from the top figure
ax1.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks()[1:]) # Stops the y axis overlapping

ax2 = py.subplot(212)
ax2.plot(x,z)

py.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)

py.show()
```

I believe there is a better way to remove the `xticklabels` but I can't remember it at the moment. Be careful not to just `py.set_xticks([])` as if you then ask for a grid the top plot has no `ticks`.

Comment: Thanks greg. That was helpful. How should i label my graph. ax1.xlabel('frequency') is not working.

Comment: I got that. I used set_xlabel method. Thanks. one small doubt i have is can i change my yaxis scales after it has been plotted. Like I have a yplot figure where it is not showing me that instant change i need. So can i change the y axis scale depending on how i want to see the graph after it has been plotted.

Comment: In general no, this may seem like a limitation but it is not. You should replot each time you make a change this means the figures a reproducible without manually setting limits. If you want to use the same plotting script with different data you could turn it into a function which accepts a filename and automates the setting of the ylimit. The less user input the better. To help with these things you should take a look at IPython

Comment: oh. that sounds like greek to me. I used set_ylimit() and set y limits to my convenience. I didn't know i could automate it. Any good references on ipython?

Comment: [Ipython notebook website](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) I suggest you watch a video. The most important tool is the `?` and tab completion allowing easier and faster access to python features. Regarding automation just think about why you choose your ylims each time then automate that.